# How to store sheets data to mysql in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, google-sheets

I have been trying to learn how to use the Sheetdb api today seems easy but was wondering how would I take the sheets data and insert it to a mysql table. Like how would I do it and what would I need. Here is code in the controller right now:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use SheetDB\SheetDB;

class SheetdbController extends Controller
{
public function get(){
    $sheetdb= new SheetDB('5wwy7qkrnqxt1');
    $result = $sheetdb->get();
    
    if($result){
        dd($result);
        foreach($result as $row){
            DB::table('DbSheets')->insert([
                'name' => $row->name
            ]);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Table migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('DbSheets', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name', 255)->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

So the data I get back looks like and array of objects so how would I insert this data to and existing empty mysql table?
Any and all suggestions are appreciated. If you wish to recreate the whole project here is a link to a video for the initial setup https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaWc7Nlt2EE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I an attaching snippet

```
$result = $sheetdb->get();
if($result){
    foreach($result as $row){
        DB::table('table_name')->insert([
            'id' => $row->Id,
            'name' => $row->name
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: So when I use you code I get an unexpected '{' error on the curly braces for the foreach loop is there something wrong with the syntax?

Comment: Found it you were missing a ; after the sql statement

Comment: Another question in the route should this be a post request or does it not matter?

Comment: After some trying I am unable to get your code to work not sure as to why some help would be great

Comment: `CREATE TABLE DbSheets(id varchar(20),name varchar(20));` here the is the create command I used and the updated code is in the main question

Comment: @AnshulRaj whats is the error you are facing

Comment: @AnshulRaj show me your db table

Comment: So I have made some changes since I have added a new migration to make the table and have changed the table to only show the names but the data is not being added to the mysql table @Faiz Sandhi and I have added the table migration to the main code

Comment: All the code has been updated to reflect what it is currently I was wondering if the problem can be caused due to it being a get request in the route but not sure as I have never done this before

Comment: @AnshulRaj first of all avoide creatng table name  starts with capital later, it should be like dbsheets/ db_sheets, that solves a lot of problems for later.

Comment: I believe something is wrong with the inserting as when I try a simple insert statement like  `DB::insert('insert into DbSheets (id, name) values (?, ?)', [1, 'Marc']);` it does not work I tried using the `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
` what is wrong can you try it yourself and see if it works for you? The table name is something I can fix really all I am trying is to get the google sheets data into the table

Comment: yes its working, 
DB::table('DbSheets')->insert([
  'name' => 'Hi'
 ]);

Comment: Its not working for me can you add all the code you used the routes and the libraries and all of that and did you try it with sheets file data and also I am using laravel 8.6 for version differences

Comment: what was the problem?

Comment: Time I needed to wait for a bit then check the database I was being to quick